# hide or show button in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am trying to hide or show a `button` in javascript, onload the button should be hidden.

```
function hideButton(){
    var x = document.getElementById('myDIV');
    x.style.display = 'none';
}
```

If `data.nextPageURL` has a string the button should be visable, if it does not have a string it should be hidden.

```
var x = document.getElementById('myDIV');
if(data.nextPageURL){
   x.style.display = 'block';
}
else if(data.nextPageURL == "") {
    x.style.display = 'none';
}
```

but don't know where I am going wrong.

Full ajax code:

```
function loadMore(url, data1) {
    $.ajax({
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        'type': 'POST',
        'url': url,
        'data': JSON.stringify(data1),
        'dataType': 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            //var json = JSON.stringify(data);
            var table = document.getElementById("searchList");
            for (var i=0; i < data.businesses.length ; i++) {
                var business = data.businesses[i];
                var row = table.insertRow(-1);
                var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
                var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
                var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
                var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
                var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
            }
            var x = document.getElementById('myDIV');
                if(data.nextPageURL == ""){
                    x.style.display = 'none';
            }
            else {
                x.style.display = 'block';
            }
```

Comment: What about this?
`var x = document.getElementById('myDIV');
if(data.nextPageURL == ""){
   x.style.display = 'none';
}
else {
    x.style.display = 'block';

}`

Comment: Your code looks fine in isolation. We need to see a working example of the problem in order to help you. What is `data.nextPageURL` and where is it set? Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: @GabrielChiHongLee it is not working

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan `data.nextPageURL` is generating from server

Comment: So it's coming from an AJAX request? Can you show that code

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan check my edit

Comment: If you `console.log(data.nextPageUrl)` what do you see?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan url string, that is embeded in the button, if no url it should be hidden

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan in my html code there is a loadmore button, it was showing when the page is loaded, but i want to make it visible if there is a url in the `nextPageUrl`

Answer (score 0):

you have a logical issue in your code

```
var x = document.getElementById('myDIV');
if(data.nextPageURL){
   x.style.display = 'block';
} else {
    x.style.display = 'none';
}
```

If data.nextPageURL is here you show your button else you hide it.

Comment: so the problem is not in my response but in your code, use console.log to draw data and understand what is going on

Answer (score 0):

Open the snippet and write anything inside the `nextPageURL`, then the div will appear.

```js
var x = document.getElementById('myDIV');

function hideButton() {
  if (data.nextPageUR) {
    x.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    x.style.display = 'none';
  }
}

hideButton();
```

```css
#myDIV {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id='myDIV'></div>
```

Comment: `nextPageURL` has string that is coming from server